# Deriving from QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: c++, qt4

I want to get a feeling of QT and decided to write a small hex editor. For that I need a widget that allows scrolling. After some research, I saw that QTextEdit derives from QAbstractScrollArea for that purpose. When reading the documentation of QAbstractScrollArea, I found the method "setViewport()" with the description "The QAbstractScrollArea will take ownership of the given widget.". This does not fit into the context of a widget that displays itself on its own. It fits only in the context of QScrollArea.

What is the appropriate way in QT to create a widget with scrollbars that displays its own content?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QAbstactScrollArea` can't display anything "itself", and the doc clearly states that:

> QAbstractScrollArea is a low-level abstraction of a scrolling area.
>   The area provides a central widget called the viewport, in which the
>   contents of the area is to be scrolled (i.e, the visible parts of the
>   contents are rendered in the viewport).
>
> Next to the viewport is a vertical scroll bar, and below is a
>   horizontal scroll bar. When all of the area contents fits in the
>   viewport, each scroll bar can be either visible or hidden depending on
>   the scroll bar's Qt::ScrollBarPolicy. When a scroll bar is hidden, the
>   viewport expands in order to cover all available space. When a scroll
>   bar becomes visible again, the viewport shrinks in order to make room
>   for the scroll bar.

Since the `QAbstractScrollArea` itself takes the ownership of it's Viewport, it's perfectly fine, and you don't need to care about it. You can think of a combination of `QAbstractScrolArea + Viewport` as of a single element, which can be operated as a single element (well, a compound one, of course), and deleted as a single element, since taking ownership of an item means that it will be destroyed alongside with it's owner.

Comment: so the client can add a widget to the viewport but this will have no visible effect on the gui and such an effect is not desired as well?

Comment: @TobiasLangner, well, think of it in this way. The scrollarea is just a square with _something_ inside, and two scrollbars. It depends on you what do you put inside of it. It can be a picture, a table, 3d render, or anything else. And by the way, the reason why `QTextEdit` is derived from `QAbstractScrollArea`, and not from `QScrollArea`, is because you want to scroll the text by rows, not by pixels, and `QScrollArea` scrolls by pixels. Most of the times, `QScrollArea` will be enough to suit your needs without needing to derive your own class.

Comment: ok, then I'll have a closer look at QTextEdit - because I need to scroll by lines as well. Thx.